# F# apply function to values in each node of list tree

Tags: f#

I have a tree of type `type T<'a> = N of 'a * T<'a> list`

An example declaration could be like these:

```
let td = N("g", [])
let tc = N("c", [N("d", []); N("e", [td])])
```

What I'd like to do is to declare a method to apply a function which returns the tree with the result of applying the function to each value in the nodes of the tree. I've done is using fold below, but is it possible to do without?

```
let rec foldTree f e (N(x,t)) = 
    List.fold (mapFold f) (f e x) t
```

Example usage for reverting the output list order:

```
foldTree (fun a x -> x::a) [] tc |> (printf "%A")
```

which FSI outputs as

```
["c"; "d"; "e"; "g"]val it : unit = ()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't gone through the excellent [Recursive types and folds](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/series/recursive-types-and-folds.html) series, you might want to read through it; that will show you a set of good approaches for handling self-recursive data structures like your tree type. The general rule for working through trees is "do what I need to do on this level, then recursively call the current function on the child nodes". Here, that would look like this:

```
let rec treeMap f tree =
    match tree with
    | N (data, children) ->
        N (f data, children |> List.map (treeMap f))
```

Note how this actually gives you back the same tree structure that you started with, rather than flattening the structure the way your `List.fold` example did.

I hope this is simple enough to be clear without a long explanation, but if you're having any trouble understanding how this code works, let me know and I'll try to explain further.

Comment: Thanks, that makes good sense. I just starting on the very same article series you posted. I think my main problem with F# so far is that I have difficulties wrapping my head around the way of thinking, in this example simply matching on the tree, calling the function on only the leaves and then let List.map handle creating the list. It just seems so simple when being presented with the solution.

Comment: Two good ways to get more comfortable with F#: go through the [F# track at Exercism](http://exercism.io/languages/fsharp) for some good exercises to get your teeth into the syntax (and look at other people's solutions once you're done), and read some code from good F# projects like [Argu](https://github.com/fsprojects/Argu), [Suave](https://github.com/SuaveIO/suave) and [F# Formatting](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Formatting). That's basically how I went from beginner to comfortable: reading other people's code and getting inspired.